# Splitting a bimodal distribution

Tags: r

On CV there is a post about this ([see here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57993/how-to-explain-how-i-divided-a-bimodal-distribution-based-on-kernel-density-esti/78397#78397)) and there is a response to it by Adrian in R seen below (or on original link). However, my problem to R masters is I am not sure what the `uniroot` part of this function is doing. Because, I sometimes get this error

```
Error in uniroot(f = f, lower = -10, upper = 10) : 
  f() values at end points not of opposite sign
```

and so I changed the `lower` to `-1` and for some of the datasets it fixed it, but still errors out on others. Not sure if that can be dynamically set based on the input vector (i.e., `x`). 
Advise?

```
library(mixtools)

simulate <- function(lambda=0.3, mu=c(0, 4), sd=c(1, 1), n.obs=10^5) {
    x1 <- rnorm(n.obs, mu[1], sd[1])
    x2 <- rnorm(n.obs, mu[2], sd[2])    
    return(ifelse(runif(n.obs) < lambda, x1, x2))
}

x <- simulate()

model <- normalmixEM(x=x, k=2)
index.lower <- which.min(model$mu)  # Index of component with lower mean

find.cutoff <- function(proba=0.5, i=index.lower) {
    ## Cutoff such that Pr[drawn from bad component] == proba
    f <- function(x) {
        proba - (model$lambda[i]*dnorm(x, model$mu[i], model$sigma[i]) /
                     (model$lambda[1]*dnorm(x, model$mu[1], model$sigma[1]) + model$lambda[2]*dnorm(x, model$mu[2], model$sigma[2])))
        }
        return(uniroot(f=f, lower=-10, upper=10)$root)  # Careful with division by zero if changing lower and upper
}

cutoffs <- c(find.cutoff(proba=0.5), find.cutoff(proba=0.75))  # Around c(1.8, 1.5)

hist(x)
abline(v=cutoffs, col=c("red", "blue"), lty=2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uniroot` is a unidimensional root finding algorithm.  You need to have bracketed the root before you call it; to ensure that this is the case, `uniroot` checks to see that the endpoints of the interval have opposite signs (I'm sure you can see how that implies that the root has been bracketed.)  Without that, there is a) no guarantee that there even is a root in the input interval, and b) no way that algorithms such as bisection can find the root, unless they get lucky.

Are you sure you want `dnorm` in the `find.cutoff` function and not `pnorm` (the cumulative density)?  If, for example, you set the standard deviations = 10, there's no value of the probability density function that will be > an input `proba` of 0.5, so there won't be a root at all.

Comment: first thanks for pnorm comment. I am leaning with you on this but I need more pondering. About that lower value, so what would be the best value? Basically, cant it be set dynamically depending on the input distribution one gives it?

Comment: Yes, just pass a parameter instead of a number, e.g., sort `x`, then `lower = x[2], upper = x[length(x)-1]`.

Comment: sorry, but that did not work :( but i think it is the sort part... i googled it but couldnt find what is really the cause 
    Error in rank(x, ties.method = "min", na.last = "keep") : 
  unimplemented type 'list' in 'greater'

Comment: Or try `lower = as.numeric(quantile(x,0.05)), upper=as.numeric(quantile(x,0.95))`.

Comment: thx for your help. So All that works, but sometimes still I get Error in uniroot(f = f, lower = as.numeric(quantile(x, 0.05)), upper = as.numeric(quantile(x,  : 
  f() values at end points not of opposite sign

Comment: PS: i also tried to change to 0.01 and that helped fixed some more but some stubborn datasets .... i even used min(x) but nope... so perhaps you can help suggest error capture so it does not error just prints sorry not this one. cause in a function that I have this in, if it errors, it stops everything.